# Django & gunicorn gives error: ImportError No module named 'vp.wsgi'

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

When I try to check the status of gunicorn I get the following error:

```
 gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-04-22 19:23:39 UTC; 10min ago
 Main PID: 7295 (code=exited, status=3)

Apr 22 19:23:39 vp-first gunicorn[7295]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
Apr 22 19:23:39 vp-first gunicorn[7295]:   File "/home/tony/vp/vpenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/guni
Apr 22 19:23:39 vp-first gunicorn[7295]:     __import__(module)
Apr 22 19:23:39 vp-first gunicorn[7295]: ImportError: No module named 'vp.wsgi'
Apr 22 19:23:39 vp-first gunicorn[7295]: [2017-04-22 19:23:39 +0000] [7300] [INFO] Worker exiting (pi
Apr 22 19:23:39 vp-first gunicorn[7295]: [2017-04-22 19:23:39 +0000] [7295] [INFO] Shutting down: Mas
Apr 22 19:23:39 vp-first gunicorn[7295]: [2017-04-22 19:23:39 +0000] [7295] [INFO] Reason: Worker fai
Apr 22 19:23:39 vp-first systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=3/NOT
Apr 22 19:23:39 vp-first systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 22 19:23:39 vp-first systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

It says ImportError: No module named 'vp.wsgi'

When I edit my gunicorn configuration file the following is in there:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=tony
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/tony/vp/vp
ExecStart=/home/tony/vp/vpenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/tony/vp/vp/vp.sock vp.wsgi:$

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have to note that my wsgi.py file is located:

```
~/vp/vp/vp/vp/wsgi.py
```

My virtualenv is located at:

```
~/vp/vpenv
```

My settings are located at:

```
~/vp/vp/vp/config/settings/production.py
```

I suppose there is something wrong with my path but I have tried a lot of things and they do not work. Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

P.s. I can't find any .sock file

Comment: Since your question requires to understand whole stack of your setup I suggest you starting with a tutorial. 

http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/10/29/serving-multiple-django-applications-with-nginx-gunicorn-supervisor/

I have used this tutorial to setup my stack. I think you better go with something like this.

Comment: @sinanUlker I am currently following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04